# Any way to bring back the accent colored close button from 20.04 and previous in newer versions?

Tags: themes, gui, 22.04, colors, yaru

[Accented Close Button in 20.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebniE.png)
[Unaccented close button on 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICj24.png)

I was excited about the added ability to change the accent color without needing a custom theme, one of the prominent spots to see said accent color was in the close button, and has been colored since at least 12.04.

It appears that accent has been removed in 22.04. I support some non-technical users and I'm afraid this change could cause confusion with them too (similar things have caused confusion in the past)

Curious if anyone knows how to get this back?

Answer (score 2):

In preparation of the future, GTK4 and libadwaita, Ubuntu has updated its Yaru theme, such that both GTK3 applications and GTK4 applications look surprisingly similar. In order to do that, the color on the close button was abandonned, because that is not possible with libadwaita. If they would preserve the colored close button, GTK4 applications would look out of place with their grey close button.

It may be possible to install an older Yaru theme without too much issues on the current Ubuntu version. That would give you the colored close buttons back, but GTK4 applications would not follow. That may not be noticeable yet, because Ubuntu carefully avoided including GTK4 applications in the default Ubuntu 22.04 desktop. All these that, upstream, were moved to GTK4 are replaced by an earlier GTK3 version. Any GTK4 application you add, however, would not have a colored close button.

Comment: Thank you for sharing what you know, I haven't seen anyone talk about this so it's nice to know there's a technical reason. I'm sure Ubuntu wouldn't want to do it since it seems like a hacky solution, but themeing libadwaita is still possible. https://github.com/odziom91/libadwaita-theme-changer